# How can i achieve Uniformity in Multi select box?

Tags: multi-select

I have 8 different Multi-Picklist box in my vf Page.But since the size of the box in are not uniform .it looks messy in the UI.Please help me out in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Rabi

Comment: What kind of solution are you looking for? Could you maybe share a screenshot? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Take a look at this question and answers: [Need to change the width of multi-select picklist on VF page](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/8464/154).  The question is asking about the inlineEdit lightbox, but the answers apply to the non-lightbox multi-selects.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the number of items that are displayed in the UI for a multi-picklist type field you can set that in the object definition. In salesforce web, that would be "# Visible Lines" under Picklist (Multi-Select) Options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS in the Style parameter of the fields, for example

```
style="width:250px;height:71px;position:absolute;"
```